# getting wrong or nothing for password_verify return value

Tags: php

`password_verify` function should return `true` or `false`  - [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

I'm getting `1` or nothing

```
$hash = password_hash('lorem ipsum', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
echo $hash; // ok
echo (password_verify('lorem ipsum', $hash)); // returns 1
echo (password_verify('abc', $hash));  // returns nothing
```

what is the problem?

Comment: You're converting a boolean to a string when you `echo` it. `true` becomes `"1"` and `false` becomes `""`. So... you're seeing exactly what you're supposed to see. If you want to see `true` or `false`, use `var_export()` or `var_dump()` for debugging.

Comment: `FALSE` becomes an empty string when you convert it to a string.